# Cobertura ant script is missing Log4J classes

Tags: java, ant, build-process, code-coverage, cobertura

I tried to get **Cobertura** running inside my ant script, but I'm stuck right at the beginning. When I try to insert the cobertura *taskdef* I'm missing the Log4J libraries.

### Ant properties & classpath

```
<property name="cobertura.dir" location="/full/path/to/cobertura-1.9.3" />
<path id="cobertura.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${cobertura.dir}">
        <include name="cobertura.jar" />
        <include name="lib/**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<taskdef classpathref="cobertura.classpath" resource="tasks.properties" />
```

### My ant target

```
<!-- ================================= 
      target: cobertura              
     ================================= -->
<target name="cobertura" depends="clean, init" description="Generates cobertura coverage reports">
    <cobertura-instrument todir="${dir.build.instrumented}">
        <fileset dir="${dir.build}">
            <include name="**/*.class" />
        </fileset>
    </cobertura-instrument>
</target>
```

I think I did everything like it is described in the [Cobertura documentation](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html) but I get this

### Ant build error

```
BUILD FAILED
build.xml:95: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
```

Inside the ***${cobertura.dir}*** there is the ***lib*** directory with all files. I unzipped it from the cobertura distribution ZIP directly into that directory.

Am I missing a step? Something wrong with my configuration so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also encountered this problem today and solved it by specifying the location of all the required libraries as part of the class path provided to my taskDef task.

```
<path id="cobertura.class.path">
    <pathelement location="${common.dir}/../tools/cobertura/cobertura.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${common.dir}/../tools/cobertura/lib/asm-3.0.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${common.dir}/../tools/cobertura/lib/asm-tree-3.0.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${common.dir}/../tools/cobertura/lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${common.dir}/../tools/cobertura/lib/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar" />
</path>

<taskdef classpathref="cobertura.class.path" resource="tasks.properties" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your ant/lib dir and make sure there is NO file cobertura.jar there. If it's there - remove it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

`<include name="lib/**/*.jar" />`

to

`<include name="*.jar" />`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to the latest cobertura and mine works fine.  Is it possible that something else is on the CLASSPATH with a different version of log4j so it is picking up wrong one?

Comment: Hm, I just tried to build it outside of my Eclipse, with manually set CLASSPATH and it works. I have to check what Eclipse is doing to my classpath... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that classpath used in taskdef and cobertura-instrument are the same. This helped me with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem, I just added all jars given with cobertura in the classpath to resolve this issue